# SAP .NET Connector 3.0 Error: "client with wrong appc header version rejected"

Tags: .net, connector, sap-dotnet-connector

I am in the process of upgrading our software to use the SAP .NET Connector 3.0 (from the .NET Connector 1.0). All of the function calls are executed successfully, however, periodically we get the following error that is repeated 4 times:

> Unhandled Exception: SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcCommunicationException:
>
> LOCATION    CPIC (TCP/IP) on local host with Unicode
>
> ERROR       client with wrong appc header version rejected
>
> TIME        Fri Aug 17 09:40:35 2012
>
> RELEASE     720
>
> COMPONENT   CPIC (TCP/IP) with Unicode
>
> VERSION     3
>
> RC          246
>
> MODULE      r3cpic.c
>
> LINE        8554
>
> DETAIL      client version 6, gateway version 120 (xxx.xx.x.xx/3301)
>
> COUNTER     2

The stack trace for this error is:

> at SAP.Middleware.Connector.CpicConnection.CpicReceive(Int32 timeout)

Immediately after that error another error is thrown 4 times:

> destination x failed when calling RFC_METADATA_GET -- see log for details

The stack trace for this error is:

> at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcRepository.Execute(RfcFunction function)

The error does not seem to be related to any particular function call but, rather, it occurs periodically (approx. 20-30 minutes at present) for any of them.

The version of the DLLs that I am using are as follows:

> sapnco.dll               3.0.2.0
>
> sapnco_utils.dll        3.0.2.0

I am afraid that I don't really know my way around the new .NET Connector yet and would be very grateful if anyone had any thoughts, clues or suggestions.

Yours,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also had problems (albeit not the same one) using version 3.0.2.0 of the .NET Connector.

I believe there is now version 3.0.6.0 or higher, so try and get hold of this. There are a number of confirmed bugs in version 3.0.2.0, one of which is something do to with the connection pooling, I believe. This may be indirectly causing your problem.

I was going to point you in the direction of the [SCN](http://scn.sap.com/community/interoperability/microsoft-net), but I see you've already found it - see the last [response](http://scn.sap.com/message/13490610#13490610) to my question slightly under yours indicating the above.

Comment: Thanks, Gareth. I'll download the new version and see if that works.

Comment: That did it, Gareth. Marked as answer.

Comment: That problem was caused by a timing problem (with slow networks) and was fixed in version 3.0.6.0. See also SAP Note 1664732.